# Keep browser locked to bottom when streaming content

Tags: python, flask

I'm using a python generator to periodically send new data back to the client via flask.Response. I can see the new data getting added into the client browser properly -- The new data is always appended to the bottom (as expected).

How can I command the browser scroll to 'lock' to the bottom of the screen so that as the updates stream in the browser is always looking at the latest data?

Comment: As a user I would expect new data to be at the top, is there a reason to not do it this way?

Comment: For a couple reasons. First more practical -- This is the natural flow of data as the generator feeding flask.Response makes it to the client (ie: data is appended) But logically, this is also the natural format of the log data being presented -- later events show up below prior ones.

Comment: Ok, so its a log, thats explains your choice